# Images in AWS S3 not loading

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Am trying to add an image to index.html in the root bucket pointing to the folder in the bucket called images. But the image is not displaying and has this strange parse:

```
<Error>
<Code>
PermanentRedirect
</Code>
   <Message>
     The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
   </Message>
   <Bucket>
   images
   </Bucket>
   <Endpoint>
   s3.amazonaws.com
   </Endpoint>
   <RequestId>
   ...
   </RequestId>
   <HostId>
   ...
   </HostId>
</Error>
```

Why is it making images a bucket? If I put the image in the bucket, it displays!

Comment: What is the URL you're using to view the image? Are you uploading the image programmatically? If so, can you please share your code?

Comment: I just opened the index.html and right clicked on the non-displayed image and got the code above. This is a simple html file; nothing being done programmatically. Also, I altered the bucket policy to grant public access to all owner objects.

Comment: What is the value of the `src` attribute for the `<img>` in your HTML markup?

Comment: /images/foo.jpg

Comment: Make it a relative path `./images/foo.jpg`

Comment: Oh boy. That worked. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jay's suggestion to use the relative path to the source helped.